# Was made vs is made

Tags: word-choice

If I want to rephrase this sentence:  Tony invented this story.
I will say: This story is made by Tony
Or
This story was made by Tony.
Or
Something else/ different

Comment: I believe that it is made (i do not know, this is me that asked the question)  because Tony is not dead or sth else but on the other hand the original sentence uses part tenses ( invented)  .I do not know.

Comment: "This story was made by Tony" makes more sense unless Tony is writing the story right now.

Comment: How about *This story is by Tony*?

Comment: 'This story was _made up_ (invented) by Tony'. If the story is finished, the action of inventing it  happened in the past. _Made_ is more often used of physical objects - 'This box was made by Tony'.

Comment: We need more context. Without any context, Gustavson's answer is the most natural, along with "Tony wrote this story", or "The story was written by Tony". But perhaps in the specific context you're asking about, there's a good reason why "invented" or "made" would be better choices. For example, is Tony a writer? Is Tony lying about something? Is he telling tall tales in the locker room"?

Answer (score 1):

Either tense of the verb could be fine but changes the connotation slightly.
However, typically, "made" isn't used to talk about written work. Instead, we might say use the verb "to write."

"This story was written by Tony" - this means that the story is finished and Tony created it in the past.

"This story is written by Tony" - implies that the story is ongoing or in progress.

Here are some other ways of phrasing this that feel natural:

- "Tony wrote this story."
- "Tony made up this story." ("made up" emphasizes the creative aspect)
- "This story was created by Tony."
- "Tony is telling this story"
- "This story is by Tony"

If you are going for the idea that Tony invented the story or came up with the idea, I recommend using verbs like "made up" "created" "invented" or "imagined."

If you are talking about the result that was produced (a book or verbal retelling), verbs like "wrote" "penned" "crafted" or "told" are more applicable.